# Posting State to firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I am trying to post `name` from state to firebase, and keep getting status 405.

I have tried changing how i import and send the data, but I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

**Index.js:**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import firebase from "firebase";

import { firebaseConfig } from "./firebase";

import Header from "./components/Header";

import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("Ryan");

  const handleClick = e => {
    console.log("Working");
    axios.post(
      "https://lq-time-tracking.firebaseio.com/",
      { name },
      { firebaseConfig }
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Header name={name} handleClick={handleClick} setName={setName} />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Header.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";

import "../style.css";

const Header = ({ name, handleClick, setName }) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <Link className="nav-item" to="/contact">
          Contact
        </Link>
        <Link className="nav-item" to="/about">
          About
        </Link>
        <Link className="nav-item" to="/home">
          Home
        </Link>
      </nav>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/home"
          render={(...props) => (
            <Home name={name} handleClick={handleClick} setName={setName} />
          )}
        />

      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

**Home.js:**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

const Home = ({ name, setName, handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>This is my State: {name}</h1>
      <input type="text" onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="Submit" onClick={e => handleClick(e)}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaking, since you use `https://lq-time-tracking.firebaseio.com` (which is a Firebase Realtime Database URL) I understand that you are trying to write the value `name` to the Realtime Database by performing a `POST` request to the `https://lq-time-tracking.firebaseio.com` URL.

This will not work because, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start), while you can use the Firebase Realtime Database URL as a REST endpoint, **you "need to append .json to the end of the URL"**.

In addition, in your case, I think you should use a [`PUT`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-put) since you just want to  write a string to your Firebase database.

It is not clear in your question, where you want to write the data in the database, but if you want to write the value `name` to the `name` subnode of the `users/user1` node, you would do as follows:

```
axios.put("https://lq-time-tracking.firebaseio.com/users/user1.json", {name})
```